# How can nodejs write object to both jsonfile and neo4j database

Tags: node.js, express, neo4j

I am not able to write my JavaScript object into Jsonfile and at the same time update a remote neo4j database.
Separately each of the functions work, but not together.
The functions are cypher.createAsset(asset) for sending query to neo4j database,
and jsonWriter.addAsset(asset) for writing to jsonfile, both are in separate modules
This is my post route that gets the form data known as 'asset'
routes/postpage.js

```
router.post('/postpage', function (req, res, next) {
    var asset = req.body;
    cypher.createAsset(asset)
    jsonWriter.addAsset(asset)
});
```

This is the module that writes to jsonfile
/jsonWriter.js

```
jsonWriter.addAsset = function(asset){
    var id = asset.projectId
    for(i=0; i< jsonFile.projects.length; i++){
        if(jsonFile.projects[i].id == id){
            jsonFile.projects[i].assets.push(asset);
            jsonFile.projects[i].assetTotal += 1;
        } 
    }
    fs.writeFileSync( 'app/data/data.json', JSON.stringify(jsonFile), 'utf8', function (err) {
        console.error(err)
    })
}
```

This is the module that send query to neo4j database
/cypherMod.js

```
cypher.createAsset = function(asset){
    var session = driver.session();
    session
    .run(`CREATE (n:ASSET{
                id:'${asset.id}',
                name:'${asset.name}',
                coordLat :'${asset.coordLat}',
                coordLng :'${asset.coordLng}',
                projectId :'${asset.projectId}'
                }) 
            RETURN n`)
    .then(function(result) {
        result.records.forEach(function(record) {
            console.log(record)
        });
        session.close();
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
}
```

Comment: Do you get any specific errors when you call both? Does only one of the functions work? If yes, which one?

Comment: FYI, your cypher and json function are both async but they have no return. You should return a Future, so in your express controller, you should be able to wait their response and see what happened.

Comment: Thanks guys. I think the node application just hangs  when the two function are included but separately each of them work.

Comment: @ logisima, I tried the return calls as you suggested but I am still not positive response, I added return jsonFile like this
   } return jsonFile;
  fs.writeFileSync( 'app/data/data.json', JSON.stringify(jsonFile), 'utf8', function (err) {
     console.error(err)
     
    })
}

Comment: @logisima, Thanks again, I added a "return jsonFile" in the jsonWriter.js , and a "return result" in the cypherMod.js , and in the "router.post "function in routes/pospage.js  I set an if condition for the processes to wait for each other